# Clickable link from text on canvas in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, hyperlink, anchor

I have a video game made in JavaScript using the createjs library.

In the credits, I draw a URL on the canvas as text, but I wish to make it a clickable link.

[image: I wish to make the above two links clickable.]

After a lot of Googling and searching through forums I haven't found a similar question being asked.

I tried using the [String link() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_link.asp), but it does not work. The game launches but the credits won't open.

```
    var oLink = new createjs.Text("www.amzd.hr"," 20px "+FONT_GAME, "#000080");
    oLink.y = +270;
    oLink.textAlign = "center";
    oLink.textBaseline = "middle";
    oLink.x = +100;
    oLink.lineWidth = 300;
    let oLink = oLink.link("https://www.amzd.hr");
    _oPanelContainer.addChild(oLink);
```

Comment: "_draw a URL on the canvas_" is the problem. Canvas is just an image, it doesn't contain any elements. A simple way would be to position a real `a` element absolutely over the canvas. It's also possible to detect the cliked pixels on the canvas, but to recognize some text requires a lot of scripting.

Comment: An easier way would be to get the clicked coordinates, and redirect with JS, if the click hits the rectangle surrounding the "link".

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener to the Text instance that opens your link.

```
oLink.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    window.open("https://url");
});
```

One note is that hit areas on text are pixel perfect, so you will want to add a hitArea. Here is some pseudo-code using [getBounds()](https://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/DisplayObject.html#method_getBounds) to determine the text size.

```
var b = oLink.getBounds();
oLink.hitArea = new createsjs.Shape(
    new createjs.Graphics().drawRect(b.x, b.y, b.width, b.height)
));
```

There is a tutorial on mouse interaction here:
https://createjs.com/tutorials/Mouse%20Interaction/

Cheers,